# Mediacodec decoder always times out while decoding H264 file

Tags: android, surfaceview, decode, h.264, android-mediacodec

I have been trying to **decode** a video file which is encoded via **H264 encoding** with Android's **MediaCodec** and tried to put the output of the decoder to a **surface**, but when I run the app it shows a black surface and in DDMS logcat I see that **decoder timed out**.

I have parsed the file into valid **frames** first [reading 4 bytes first which indicates the length of the upcoming frame and then read length amount bytes which indicates the frame, then again reading 4 bytes for the length of the next frame and so on.] then passed the frames to the decoder in a loop. When configuring the decoder, I passed **sps & pps** in the **mediaFormat** by hardcoding values directly from the encoded file [I got those values by opening that file with hexedit]. I did **not** set any **presentationTimeUS** and used 0 for it. Now the decoder's **dequeInputBuffer()** method returns >=0 value but **dequeOutputBuffer()** only returns **MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER** which eventually means the decoder is being timed out.

Please have a look at my code and please help.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the file url - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B39qOyEnXlR8Z3FSb2lzTWlORUU/edit?usp=sharing

Here is my code -

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{

    private static final String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/H264Data1.264"; // + "/video_encoded.263";//"/video_encoded.264";
    private PlayerThread mPlayer = null;
    Handler handler = null;
    public static byte[] SPS = null;
    public static byte[] PPS = null;
    public static ArrayList<Frame> frames = null;
    public static int frameID = 0;
    public static boolean incompleteLastFrame = false;
    File encodedFile = new File(filePath);
    InputStream is;

    private static class Frame
    {
        public int id;
        public byte[] frameData;

        public Frame(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try 
        {
            is = new FileInputStream(encodedFile);
            byte[] data = new byte[(int)encodedFile.length()];

            System.out.println("Total file size : " + encodedFile.length());
            frameID = 0;
            frames = new ArrayList<Frame>();

            try {
                if ((is.read(data, 0, (int)encodedFile.length())) != -1) 
                {
                    getFramesFromData(data);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "frames processing finished. number of frames : " + frames.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(this);
                    handler = new Handler();
                    sv.getHolder().addCallback(this);
                    setContentView(sv);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public static void getFramesFromData(byte[] data) 
    {
        int dataLength = data.length;
        int frameLength = 0;
        frameID = 0;

        if(data.length <= 0) return;

        // each iteration in this loop indicates generation of a new frame
        for(int i = 0; ; )
        {
            if(i+3 >= dataLength) return;

            frameLength = ((data[i] & 0xff) << 24)
                    + ((data[i + 1] & 0xff) << 16)
                    + ((data[i + 2] & 0xff) << 8)
                    + (data[i + 3] & 0xff);

            i += 4;

            if(frameLength > 0)
            {
                if(i+frameLength-1 >= dataLength) return;
                Frame frame = new Frame(frameID);
                frame.frameData = new byte[frameLength];
                System.arraycopy(data, i, frame.frameData, 0, frameLength);
                frames.add(frame);
                frameID++;
                i += frameLength;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "in surfaceCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) 
    {
        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "in surfaceChanged");
        if (mPlayer == null) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in surfaceChanged. creating playerthread", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mPlayer = new PlayerThread(holder.getSurface());
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        if (mPlayer != null) 
        {
            mPlayer.interrupt();    
        }
    }

    private class PlayerThread extends Thread 
    {
        //private MediaExtractor extractor;
        private MediaCodec decoder;
        private Surface surface;

        public PlayerThread(Surface surface) 
        {
            this.surface = surface;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            handler.post(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run() 
                {

                    decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
                    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 320, 240);

                    byte[] header_sps  = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, (byte)0x80, 0x0C, (byte)0xE4, 0x40, (byte)0xA0, (byte)0xFD, 0x00, (byte)0xDA, 0x14, 0x26, (byte)0xA0 };
                    byte[] header_pps = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, (byte)0xCE, 0x38, (byte)0x80 };
                    mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(header_sps));
                    mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(header_pps));

                    decoder.configure(mediaFormat, surface /* surface */, null /* crypto */, 0 /* flags */);

                    if (decoder == null) 
                    {
                        Log.e("DecodeActivity", "Can't find video info!");
                        return;
                    }

                    decoder.start();
                    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "decoder.start() called");

                    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
                    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();


                    long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    int i = 0;
                    while(!Thread.interrupted())
                    {
                        if(i >= frames.size()) 
                            break;
                        byte[] data = new byte[frames.get(i).frameData.length];
                        System.arraycopy(frames.get(i).frameData, 0, data, 0, frames.get(i).frameData.length);
                        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "i = " + i + " dataLength = " + frames.get(i).frameData.length);

                        int inIndex = 0; 
                        while ((inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1)) < 0)
                            ;

                        if (inIndex >= 0) 
                        {
                            ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
                            buffer.clear();
                            int sampleSize = data.length;
                            if (sampleSize < 0) 
                            {
                                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                                break;
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "sample size: " + sampleSize);

                                buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length);
                                buffer.put(data);
                                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, 0, 0);
                            }


                            BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
                            int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 100000);

                            switch (outIndex) 
                            {
                            case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                                outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                                break;
                            case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat());

                                break;
                            case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
                                try {
                                    sleep(100);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                ByteBuffer outbuffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];

                                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "We can't use this buffer but render it due to the API limit, " + outbuffer);

                                /*while (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) 
                                {
                                    try 
                                    {
                                        sleep(10);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }*/

                                decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                                break;
                            }
                            i++;
                            // All decoded frames have been rendered, we can stop playing now
                            /*if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) 
                            {
                                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "OutputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                                break;
                            }*/

                        }
                    }

                    decoder.stop();
                    decoder.release();
                }
            });         
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part looks wrong:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
[...]
buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length);
buffer.put(data);
decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, 0, 0);
```

You're getting the input buffer, and then ignoring it in favor of a buffer you're allocating yourself.  Replace the `ByteBuffer.allocate()` call with `buffer.clear()`.

What you're doing is pretty similar to the check pass in [DecodeEditEncodeTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#DecodeEditEncodeTest), except that the latter is just holding the whole thing in memory instead of serializing it to disk.  Take a look at `checkVideoData()`.

You may want to adopt the test's approach of serializing the chunk flags out with the data.  If you did that, you wouldn't need to treat the SPS/PPS header specially -- just write it to the stream like any other chunk (it just happens to have the `CODEC_CONFIG` flag set).  It would also be a good idea to serialize the time stamp unless the input video is guaranteed to have a known, non-varying frame rate.

Comment: Thanks @fadden, it was great help. Now I'm very close to what I was actually trying to do - streaming video directly from the camera. But, now I am facing another problem about the color & the orientation of the output video. Can you please have a look at my [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131661/mediacodec-video-streaming-from-camera-wrong-orientation-color)