# MediaCodec Video Streaming From Camera wrong orientation & color

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, video-encoding, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to stream video capturing **directly from camera** for android devices. So far I have been able to capture each frame from android camera's **onPreviewFrame**(byte[] data, Camera camera) function, encode the data & then successfully decode the data and show to the surface. I used android's **MediaCodec** for the encoding & decoding. But the **color & the orientation** of the video is not correct [ **90 degree rotated** ]. After searching a while I have found this YV12toYUV420PackedSemiPlanar function - if I use this function on the raw camera data before passing it to the encoder the color comes out correct but it is **still 90 degree rotated**.

```
public static byte[] YV12toYUV420PackedSemiPlanar(final byte[] input, final int width, final int height) {

    final int frameSize = width * height;
    final int qFrameSize = frameSize/4;
    byte[] output = new byte[input.length];


    System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, frameSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < (qFrameSize); i++) 
    {
        byte b = (input[frameSize + qFrameSize + i - 32 - 320]);
        output[frameSize + i*2] =   b;
        output[frameSize + i*2 + 1] = (input[frameSize + i - 32 - 320]);            
    }
    System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, frameSize); // Y
    for (int i = 0; i < qFrameSize; i++) {
        output[frameSize + i*2] = input[frameSize + i + qFrameSize]; // Cb (U)
        output[frameSize + i*2 + 1] = input[frameSize + i]; // Cr (V)
    }
    return output;
}
```

[image]

Then I used this function, rotateYUV420Degree90 **after** calling YV12toYUV420PackedSemiPlanar function. It seems the **orientation and the color is ok** but the output video is very **distorted**.

```
private byte[] rotateYUV420Degree90(byte[] data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) 
{
    byte [] yuv = new byte[imageWidth*imageHeight*3/2];
    // Rotate the Y luma
    int i = 0;
    for(int x = 0;x < imageWidth;x++)
    {
        for(int y = imageHeight-1;y >= 0;y--)                               
        {
            yuv[i] = data[y*imageWidth+x];
            i++;
        }
    }
    // Rotate the U and V color components 
    i = imageWidth*imageHeight*3/2-1;
    for(int x = imageWidth-1;x > 0;x=x-2)
    {
        for(int y = 0;y < imageHeight/2;y++)                                
        {
            yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth*imageHeight)+(y*imageWidth)+x];
            i--;
            yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth*imageHeight)+(y*imageWidth)+(x-1)];
            i--;
        }
    }
    return yuv;
}
```

[image]

Because of my very little knowledge on color specs and camera data I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Here is my total code - please have a look and help me finding my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback  {

    Camera mCamera;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    File mVideoFile;
    MediaCodec mMediaCodec;
    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers;
    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers;
    MySurfaceView cameraSurfaceView ;
    SurfaceView decodedSurfaceView ;
    LinearLayout ll;
    RelativeLayout rl;
    Button btn;
    boolean mPreviewRunning = false;
    boolean firstTime = true;
    boolean isRunning = false;
    public static final String ENCODING = "h264";  

    private PlayerThread mPlayer = null;
    Handler handler = null;
    public static byte[] SPS = null;
    public static byte[] PPS = null;
    public static int frameID = 0;
    BlockingQueue<Frame> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Frame>(100);

    private static class Frame
    {
        public int id;
        public byte[] frameData;

        public Frame(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        cameraSurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
        if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h264"))
        {
            cameraSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams(320, 240));
        }
        else if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h263"))
        {
            cameraSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams(352, 288));
        }
        ll.addView(cameraSurfaceView);

        initCodec();
        setContentView(ll);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        mPreviewRunning = false;

        if(cameraSurfaceView !=null && cameraSurfaceView.isEnabled())
            cameraSurfaceView.setEnabled(false);
        cameraSurfaceView = null;

        if(mCamera != null)
        {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        }

        System.exit(0);

        mMediaCodec.stop();
        mMediaCodec.release();
        mMediaCodec = null;

    };


    private void initCodec() {

        MediaFormat mediaFormat = null;

        if(mMediaCodec != null)
        {
            mMediaCodec.stop();
            mMediaCodec.release();
            mMediaCodec = null;
        }

        if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h264"))
        {
            mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
            mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc",
                    320,
                    240);
        }
        else if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h263"))
        {
            mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/3gpp");
            mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/3gpp",
                    352,
                    288);
        }

        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 125000);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 8000);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);

        try
        {
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, 
                    MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar);

            mMediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat,
                    null,
                    null,
                    MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            frameID = 0;
            mMediaCodec.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mediaformat error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**========================================================================*/
    /** This function gets the starting index of the first appearance of match array in source array. The function will search in source array from startIndex position.*/
    public static int find(byte[] source, byte[] match, int startIndex) 
    {  
        if(source == null || match == null)
        {
            Log.d("EncodeDecode", "ERROR in find : null");
            return -1;
        }
        if(source.length == 0 || match.length == 0)
        {
            Log.d("EncodeDecode", "ERROR in find : length 0");
            return -1;
        }

        int ret = -1;  
        int spos = startIndex;  
        int mpos = 0;  
        byte m = match[mpos];  
        for( ; spos < source.length; spos++ ) 
        {  
            if(m == source[spos]) 
            {  
                // starting match  
                if(mpos == 0)  
                    ret = spos;  
                // finishing match  
                else if(mpos == match.length - 1)  
                    return ret;  

                mpos++;  
                m = match[mpos];  
            }  
            else 
            {  
                ret = -1;  
                mpos = 0;  
                m = match[mpos];  
            }  
        }  
        return ret;  
    }


    /**========================================================================*/
    /** For H264 encoding, this function will retrieve SPS & PPS from the given data and will insert into SPS & PPS global arrays. */
    public static void getSPS_PPS(byte[] data, int startingIndex)
    {
        byte[] spsHeader = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67};
        byte[] ppsHeader = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68};
        byte[] frameHeader = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};

        int spsStartingIndex = -1;
        int nextFrameStartingIndex = -1;
        int ppsStartingIndex = -1;

        spsStartingIndex = find(data, spsHeader, startingIndex);
        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "spsStartingIndex: " + spsStartingIndex);
        if(spsStartingIndex >= 0)
        {
            nextFrameStartingIndex = find(data, frameHeader, spsStartingIndex+1);
            int spsLength = 0;
            if(nextFrameStartingIndex>=0)
                spsLength = nextFrameStartingIndex - spsStartingIndex;
            else
                spsLength = data.length - spsStartingIndex;
            if(spsLength > 0)
            {
                SPS = new byte[spsLength];
                System.arraycopy(data, spsStartingIndex, SPS, 0, spsLength);
            }
        }

        ppsStartingIndex = find(data, ppsHeader, startingIndex);
        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "ppsStartingIndex: " + ppsStartingIndex);
        if(ppsStartingIndex >= 0)
        {
            nextFrameStartingIndex = find(data, frameHeader, ppsStartingIndex+1);
            int ppsLength = 0;
            if(nextFrameStartingIndex>=0)
                ppsLength = nextFrameStartingIndex - ppsStartingIndex;
            else
                ppsLength = data.length - ppsStartingIndex;
            if(ppsLength > 0)
            {
                PPS = new byte[ppsLength];
                System.arraycopy(data, ppsStartingIndex, PPS, 0, ppsLength);
            }
        }
    }


    /**========================================================================*/
    /** Prints the byte array in hex */
    private void printByteArray(byte[] array)
    {
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : array) 
        {
            sb1.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
        }
        Log.d("EncodeDecode", sb1.toString());
    }

    public static byte[] YV12toYUV420PackedSemiPlanar(final byte[] input, final int width, final int height) {
        /* 
         * COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar is NV12
         * We convert by putting the corresponding U and V bytes together (interleaved).
         */
        final int frameSize = width * height;
        final int qFrameSize = frameSize/4;
        byte[] output = new byte[input.length];


        System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, frameSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < (qFrameSize); i++) 
        {
            byte b = (input[frameSize + qFrameSize + i - 32 - 320]);
            output[frameSize + i*2] =   b;
            output[frameSize + i*2 + 1] = (input[frameSize + i - 32 - 320]);            
        }



        System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, frameSize); // Y

        for (int i = 0; i < qFrameSize; i++) {
            output[frameSize + i*2] = input[frameSize + i + qFrameSize]; // Cb (U)
            output[frameSize + i*2 + 1] = input[frameSize + i]; // Cr (V)
        }
        return output;
    }

    private byte[] rotateYUV420Degree90(byte[] data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) 
    {
        byte [] yuv = new byte[imageWidth*imageHeight*3/2];
        // Rotate the Y luma
        int i = 0;
        for(int x = 0;x < imageWidth;x++)
        {
            for(int y = imageHeight-1;y >= 0;y--)                               
            {
                yuv[i] = data[y*imageWidth+x];
                i++;
            }
        }
        // Rotate the U and V color components 
        i = imageWidth*imageHeight*3/2-1;
        for(int x = imageWidth-1;x > 0;x=x-2)
        {
            for(int y = 0;y < imageHeight/2;y++)                                
            {
                yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth*imageHeight)+(y*imageWidth)+x];
                i--;
                yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth*imageHeight)+(y*imageWidth)+(x-1)];
                i--;
            }
        }
        return yuv;
    }

    /**========================================================================*/
    /** When camera receives a frame this function is called with the frame data as its parameter. It encodes the given data and then stores in frameQueue. */
    private void encode(byte[] data)
    {
        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "ENCODE FUNCTION CALLED");
        inputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
        outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();

        int inputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
        {
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
            inputBuffer.clear();

            int size = inputBuffer.limit();
            //inputBuffer.put(data);

            // color right, but rotated
            byte[] output = YV12toYUV420PackedSemiPlanar(data,320,240);
            inputBuffer.put(output);

            // color almost right, orientation ok but distorted 
            /*byte[] output = YV12toYUV420PackedSemiPlanar(data,320,240);
            output = rotateYUV420Degree90(output,320,240);
            inputBuffer.put(output);*/

            mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0 /* offset */, size, 0 /* timeUs */, 0);
            Log.d("EncodeDecode", "InputBuffer queued");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("EncodeDecode", "inputBufferIndex < 0, returning null");
            return ;
        }

        MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        int outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "outputBufferIndex = " + outputBufferIndex);
        do
        {
            if (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
            {
                Frame frame = new Frame(frameID);
                ByteBuffer outBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
                byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
                byte idrFrameType = 0x65;
                int dataLength = 0;

                outBuffer.get(outData);

                // If SPS & PPS is not ready then 
                if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h264") && ( (SPS == null || SPS.length ==0) || (PPS == null || PPS.length == 0) ) )
                    getSPS_PPS(outData, 0);

                dataLength = outData.length;

                // If the frame is an IDR Frame then adding SPS & PPS in front of the actual frame data 
                if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h264") && outData[4] == idrFrameType)
                {
                    int totalDataLength = dataLength + SPS.length + PPS.length;

                    frame.frameData = new byte[totalDataLength];

                    System.arraycopy(SPS, 0, frame.frameData, 0, SPS.length);
                    System.arraycopy(PPS, 0, frame.frameData, SPS.length, PPS.length);
                    System.arraycopy(outData, 0 , frame.frameData, SPS.length+PPS.length, dataLength);
                }
                else
                {
                    frame.frameData = new byte[dataLength];
                    System.arraycopy(outData, 0 , frame.frameData, 0, dataLength);
                }

                // for testing
                Log.d("EncodeDecode" , "Frame no :: " + frameID + " :: frameSize:: " + frame.frameData.length + " :: ");
                printByteArray(frame.frameData);

                // if encoding type is h264 and sps & pps is ready then, enqueueing the frame in the queue
                // if encoding type is h263 then, enqueueing the frame in the queue
                if( (ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h264") && SPS != null && PPS != null && SPS.length != 0 && PPS.length != 0) || ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h263") )
                {
                    Log.d("EncodeDecode", "enqueueing frame no: " + (frameID));

                    try
                    {
                        queue.put(frame);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        Log.e("EncodeDecode", "interrupted while waiting");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException e)
                    {
                        Log.e("EncodeDecode", "frame is null");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
                    {
                        Log.e("EncodeDecode", "problem inserting in the queue");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.d("EncodeDecode", "frame enqueued. queue size now: " + queue.size());

                    if(firstTime)
                    {
                        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "adding a surface to layout for decoder");
                        SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
                        handler = new Handler();
                        sv.getHolder().addCallback(MainActivity.this);
                        sv.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams(320, 240));
                        ll.addView(sv,1);
                        MainActivity.this.setContentView(ll);
                        firstTime = false;
                    }
                }

                frameID++;
                mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

            }
            else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED)
            {
                outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
                Log.e("EncodeDecode","output buffer of encoder : info changed");
            }
            else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED)
            {
                Log.e("EncodeDecode","output buffer of encoder : format changed");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("EncodeDecode", "unknown value of outputBufferIndex : " + outputBufferIndex);
                //printByteArray(data);
            }
        } while (outputBufferIndex >= 0);
    }

    private class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback  
    {
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        public MySurfaceView(Context context) {  
            super(context); 
            holder = this.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this); 
        }

        public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {  
            super(context,attrs); 
            holder = this.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this); 
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {  
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    if(mCamera == null)
                        mCamera = Camera.open();
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                    Log.d("EncodeDecode","Camera opened");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("EncodeDecode","Camera open failed");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();

                if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h264"))
                    p.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
                else if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h263"))
                    p.setPreviewSize(352, 288);

                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
                    { 
                        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "onPreviewFrame, calling encode function");
                        encode(data);
                    }
                });
                mCamera.startPreview();
                mPreviewRunning = true;
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.e("EncodeDecode","surfaceCreated():: in setPreviewDisplay(holder) function");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                Log.e("EncodeDecode","surfaceCreated Nullpointer");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) 
        {  
            if (mPreviewRunning) 
            {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                Log.e("EncodeDecode","preview stopped");
            }
            try 
            {
                if(mCamera == null)
                {
                    mCamera = Camera.open();
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                }

                Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
                if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h264"))
                    p.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
                else if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h263"))
                    p.setPreviewSize(352, 288);

                p.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.YV12);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.unlock();
                mCamera.reconnect();
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
                    {
                        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "onPreviewFrame, calling encode function");
                        encode(data);
                    }
                });
                Log.d("EncodeDecode", "previewCallBack set");
                mCamera.startPreview();
                mPreviewRunning = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("EncodeDecode","surface changed:set preview display failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
        {

        }  
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "mainActivity surfaceCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) 
    {
        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "mainActivity surfaceChanged.");
        if (mPlayer == null) 
        {
            mPlayer = new PlayerThread(holder.getSurface());
            mPlayer.start();
            Log.d("EncodeDecode", "PlayerThread started");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        if (mPlayer != null) 
        {
            mPlayer.interrupt();    
        }
    }

    private class PlayerThread extends Thread 
    {
        //private MediaExtractor extractor;
        private MediaCodec decoder;
        private Surface surface;

        public PlayerThread(Surface surface) 
        {
            this.surface = surface;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            while(SPS == null || PPS == null || SPS.length == 0 || PPS.length == 0)
            {
                try 
                {
                    Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: sps,pps not ready yet");
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }

            Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: sps,pps READY");

            if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h264"))
            {
                decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
                MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 320, 240);
                mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(SPS));
                mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(PPS));
                decoder.configure(mediaFormat, surface /* surface */, null /* crypto */, 0 /* flags */);
            }
            else if(ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase("h263"))
            { 
                decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/3gpp");
                MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/3gpp", 352, 288);
                decoder.configure(mediaFormat, surface /* surface */, null /* crypto */, 0 /* flags */);
            }

            if (decoder == null) 
            {
                Log.e("DecodeActivity", "DECODER_THREAD:: Can't find video info!");
                return;
            }

            decoder.start();
            Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: decoder.start() called");

            ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
            ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();


            int i = 0;
            while(!Thread.interrupted())
            {
                Frame currentFrame = null;
                try 
                {
                    Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: calling queue.take(), if there is no frame in the queue it will wait");
                    currentFrame = queue.take();
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    Log.e("EncodeDecode","DECODER_THREAD:: interrupted while PlayerThread was waiting for the next frame");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(currentFrame == null)
                    Log.e("EncodeDecode","DECODER_THREAD:: null frame dequeued");
                else
                    Log.d("EncodeDecode","DECODER_THREAD:: " + currentFrame.id + " no frame dequeued");

                if(currentFrame != null && currentFrame.frameData != null && currentFrame.frameData.length != 0)
                {
                    Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: decoding frame no: " + i + " , dataLength = " + currentFrame.frameData.length);

                    int inIndex = 0; 
                    while ((inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1)) < 0)
                        ;

                    if (inIndex >= 0) 
                    {
                        Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: sample size: " + currentFrame.frameData.length);

                        ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
                        buffer.clear();
                        buffer.put(currentFrame.frameData);
                        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, currentFrame.frameData.length, 0, 0);

                        BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
                        int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 100000);

                        switch (outIndex) 
                        {
                        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                            Log.e("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                            outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                            break;
                        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                            Log.e("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat());

                            break;
                        case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                            Log.e("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Log.d("EncodeDecode", "DECODER_THREAD:: decoded SUCCESSFULLY!!!");
                            ByteBuffer outbuffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
                            decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                            break;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            decoder.stop();
            decoder.release();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The camera capture orientation is fixed -- usually looks "right" when the device is in landscape.  Check the "Show + capture camera" test in Grafika for an example... if you have a Nexus 5 in portrait, the camera image will appear sideways.  Camera apps "fix" this for you behind the scenes.  For the rotation, your "before" and "after" images above appear to have the same dimensions, which seems wrong since the camera isn't taking square pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rotated the image it has newWidth = oldHeight, and newHeigth = oldWidth, since source isnt a square picture. So you have a choice either to use cropping and adjust rotation cycle respectively or to use different preview size for dispaying, now you surfaces pitch just smaller then pitch of  surfaceview or whatever component you use for display

Comment: I have the same issue. Is it possible to crop the byte data .? Since my video is distorted at the server side.

Answer (score 5):

When I'm making an app which can real time broadcast camera frames via RTMP I have same problems in portrait mode but I can solve it by using TextureView. First of all, I didn't rotate frames on the sender side. But I rotate TextureView which is linked in mediaplayer and resizing textureview on the receiver side.

[image]

I coded like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

---

```
 private void updateTextureViewSize(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        int pivotPointX = viewWidth / 2;
        int pivotPointY = viewHeight / 2;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        if(isLandscapeOrientation) {
            matrix.preRotate(0);
            matrix.setScale(1.0f, 1.0f, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);
            videoView.setTransform(matrix);
            videoView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewHeight));
        } else {
            matrix.preRotate(0);
            matrix.setScale(1.0f, 1.0f, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);
            videoView.setRotation(90);
            videoView.setTranslationX(-viewWidth / 2);
            videoView.setTranslationY(-viewHeight / 2);
            videoView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(viewWidth * 2, viewHeight * 2));
        }

    }
```

---

```
private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener surfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Surface s = new Surface(surface);
            if(mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.setSurface(s);

                DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                int sh = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
                int sw = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

                updateTextureViewSize(sw, sh);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };
```